# Rails image link_to not working

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

This is working fine

```
 <%= link_to "up.png", voteup_path(post_id: post.id, topic_id: post.topic_id), class: "xta"  %>
```

but not this

```
 <%= link_to image_tag("up.png"), voteup_path(post_id: post.id, topic_id: post.topic_id), class: "xta"  %>
```

Please tell me how i can make it work.

Comment: try this `<%=link_to( image_tag("up.png"),voteup_path(post_id: post.id, topic_id: post.topic_id), class: "xta")  %>`

Comment: glad it worked for you, added as answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, pass `image_tag` and class to `link_to` tag

```
<%=link_to( image_tag("up.png"),voteup_path(post_id: post.id, topic_id: post.topic_id), class: "xta") %>
```